# jaxb2 simplify plugin binding issue

Tags: xsd, jaxb2, xjc, jaxb2-simplify-plugin

I tried to use JAXB2 simplify plugin using the XJC 2.2.4.

```
D:\>xjc -d . -extension -p org.my.space sample.xsd parsing a schema... [ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace
"http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/simplify". Perhaps you meant
"http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"?   line 7 of file:/D:/sample.xsd
Failed to parse a schema.
```

sample.xsd has the declared simplify

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.1"
    xmlns:simplify="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/simplify"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="simplify"
    xmlns="http://www.example.org/sampleXML" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/sampleXML"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

any thoughts?

EDIT:
I tried other way around with bindings file xjb and still the same error. Does it mean my XJC version(2.2) does not support JAXB2 simplify ?

> xjc -d . -extension -b bindings.xjb sample.xsd

```
<bindings version="2.1"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:simplify="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/simplify"
      extensionBindingPrefixes="simplify">

    <bindings schemaLocation="sample.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <bindings
            node="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='dlist']/xs:choice/xs:element[1]">
            <simplify:as-element-property />
        </bindings>
    </bindings>

</bindings>
```

Comment: Is there a whitespace between `s`and  `implify`in the namespace URi or is this a typo?

Comment: sorry typo. it is corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to `maven jaxb2 plugin` and with some more efforts it worked fine. For people who have trouble in future. This setup works just fine in JDK 1.6 (for those still cant migrate).

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--  plugin to compile schemas to JAXB classes -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb21-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-JAXB</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>sample.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <cleanPackageDirectories>true</cleanPackageDirectories>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xsimplify</arg>
                    </args>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>0.11.0</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I did not use `binding.xjb` as I have included the `simplify` directly in the schema (as i have access).

**sample.xsd**

```
<xs:complexType name="doclist">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <simplify:as-element-property />
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:element name="document1" type="type1" />
            <xs:element name="document2" type="type2" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="heading" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
```